# all that vs what vs that which

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, sentence-meaning, relative-clauses

What’s the difference between these three usages?

1. **All that** glitters is not always gold.
2. **What** glitters is not always gold.
3. **That which** glitters is not always gold.

Are they interchangeable?  What kind of meanings do they convey, respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of this idiom, yes, I would say they're interchangeable. They're pronouns that are defined by the rest of the sentence that follows. But I could imagine that switching out the pronoun in this manner in another sentence or context might change the meaning slightly.

Answer (score 1):

The standard form of the expression is *all that glitters is not gold*. Shakespeare, in *The Merchant of Venice*, used *glisters*, a variant of the same word.

It's not necessary to include *always*, because in modern language we would say *Not everything that glitters is gold.* The meaning is that things that look shiny and precious are not always of real value.